# Spring Security hasIpAddress issue

Tags: spring, security

I have a method in a controller using  the below configuration:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/encore/{userName}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasIpAddress('192.168.1.2/24')")
public EncoreAccount validateUserRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
    @PathVariable(value = "userName") String userName,
    @PathVariable(value = "token") String token) {
}
```

and I have this one in webmvc-config.xml

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

But when I run it, I get the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 0): Method call: Method hasIpAddress(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot type
```

I know that the hasIpAddress() is in org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.

Do you know why it doesn't look up the method in WebSecurityExpressionRoot?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hasIpAddress()` expression is available for **web security**.

> org.springframework.security.**web**.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot

`@PreAuth` uses

> org.springframework.security.access.expression.**method**.MethodSecurityExpressionRoot

You can secure a URL (intercept) with `hasIpAddress()` but not a method.

Comment: That is so not apparent when you read the spring security docs. I'll put my note in here that you can still do this (sortof), with PreAuthorize and spel, although this doesn't account for things like proxy servers or load balancers. User @PreAuthorize("#request.getRemoteAddr().equals('127.0.0.1')")  and put a HttpServletRequest request variable in the method arguments