# Spring Boot web service designed for a specific domain

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I'd like to have a restriction on my spring boot security with allowing only a particular domain (or hostname) to make the web service calls.

The idea is to allow only one single app (based on Spring MVC) to access these webservices in the spring boot application.

**UPDATE**

I tried to incorporate hasIpAddress as shown below but it has no effect

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('localhost')");
    }
```

Is there such setting in spring security ? Or I need to use interceptor ?

Comment: Remove the permitAll section and change the host name to an IP adress or subnet, then it should work, for example:
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("hasIpAddress('192.168.0.0/24')");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spring web security there is hasIpAddress expression where in you can pass in an ip or a range.

Sample Config:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/myUrlPattern/*" access="hasIpAddress('100.10.11.12')" />

    </http>
```

More explanation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

Comment: Can I use annotation for this?

Comment: I have not specifically used annotation though, but people have reported some problems using this in annotation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351506/spring-security-hasipaddress-issue

Comment: I'll use this as a last resort. Trying not to use xml. I'll mark this as accepted if there's no better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
       .anyRequest().hasIpAddress('localhost');
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can utilize the response header to control the valid IP that can access your service. Spring Security should be used to handle User authentication and authorization in my opinion.

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/